# Migrating Swift code to Swift 3.0 LOADS of errors

Tags: swift, xcode

I've tried the default Converting tool, inside Xcode 8, but after it finished, I get hundreds of errors, which cannot be easily fixed and very weird. I think I'm doing something wrong here
Any idea?
[image]

Comment: 32 is not a big number. I've got 400+ errors in my project after converting to new Swift 3 but many of them were easily fixed by search and replace.

Comment: I want to write my code once and it should work! I don't want to spend extra time, Apple SHOULD make backward compatibility...

Comment: Can you link anything for that search and replace?

Comment: @user3341586 FWIW Apple has gone on record saying that Swift 3 will be stable going forward.

Answer (score 1):

It might be best to read through the notes received from Xcode. Take note that starting with Swift 3, it no longer used Objective-c libraries `NS`

I would start by removing all NS prefix and see what errors you have left. For example:

Swift 2.3

```
'NSCalendar'
```

Swift 3.0

Just `Calendar`

If you are working with `UIColor`, for example `UIColor.blackColor()`, Swift 3 is `UIColor.black()`

As you can see, Swift 3 is more, as we know, Swifty ;-).

Let me know how to goes and if you are stuck with other errors.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try something... Or maybe hire someone to do that, because I don't really have time for this project, but It would be important to get it up to date. Thanks

Comment: 'components' produces '[String]', not the expected contextual result type 'NSArray'            var nevnapok : NSArray = forNameDay.components(separatedBy: ", ")

Answer (score 0):

If you were on 2.2 before this migrate to 2.3 first.
Then migrate to 3.0
Here is an interesting article that lists down all the changes that have happened: You might want to check the error messages on Xcode and then find corresponding solutions to the same:

[Migration to Swift 3.0](https://buildingvts.com/a-mostly-comprehensive-list-of-swift-3-0-and-2-3-changes-193b904bb5b1)